# Change treeview attributes values C#

Tags: c#, xml, treeview, nodes

I am loading an XML file and showing it as a treeview. I would like to allow the user to see what children can each element have. Is there any way to do so?
I am having troubles matching the nodes (the tree node with the 'original' node). I compared them by name but I don't always get the correct result.
This it what I have so far:

```
                        xmlFile = new XmlDocument();
                        xmlFile.Load(dialog.FileName);
                        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
                        treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xmlFile.DocumentElement.Name));
                        TreeNode tNode = new TreeNode();
                        tNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
                        AddNode(xmlFile.DocumentElement, tNode);
                        treeView1.ExpandAll();
```

Adding the nodes

```
public void AddNode(XmlNode xmlNode, TreeNode treeNodes)
           { XmlNode xNode;
            TreeNode tNode;
            XmlNodeList nodeList;
            int i;
            if (xmlNode.HasChildNodes)
           {nodeList = xmlNode.ChildNodes;
                for (i = 0; i <= nodeList.Count - 1; i++)
                {xNode = xmlNode.ChildNodes[i];
                    treeNodes.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));
                    tNode = treeNodes.Nodes[i];
                    AddNode(xNode, tNode);}}
            else
            { treeNodes.Text = (xmlNode.OuterXml).Trim();}}
```

On tree node click

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e){         
            List<string> temp = new List<string>();
            this.lbElements.Items.Clear(););
            foreach (XmlNode node in xmlFile.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (node.Name == e.Node.Name)
                {
                 foreach (string s in fh.getChildNodes(node)) temp.Add(s);

                  if (!temp.Contains(s))
                        temp.Add(s);


                 foreach (string s in temp) this.lbElements.Items.Add(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `if (node.Name == e.Node.Text && node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)`
in the treeview_NodeMouseClick().

Comment: I have the following structure: Person- Name and email- Family and Given. When clicking on Person, I do get indeed Name and email as elements. But when I click on name, I do not get suggestions anymore. I assume I have to change my search method

Answer (score 0):

The simpest way to do is to use XmlReader and loop through the content.
I tried in this way.

>

```
  private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick_1(object sender,
> TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
>         {
>             XmlReader reader = null;
>             reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath);
>             {
>                 reader.MoveToContent();
>                 // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
>                 while (reader.Read())
>                 {
>                     switch (reader.NodeType)
>                     {
>                         case XmlNodeType.Element:
>                             if (reader.LocalName == "to")
>                             {
> 
>                             }
>                             break;
> 
>                         case XmlNodeType.Text:
>                             if(reader.Value == "Jane")
>                             {
> 
>                             }
>                             break;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }

Xml file used is:
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jane</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Weekend</body>
</note>
```

Comment: It doesn't help my case at all since I am interestend in something else. When clicking on Tove I want to see the children of that element. In this case, reader doesnt have such property/method.